# is workflow right for dynamic workflow creation in web based application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation

I am new to workflow and just know some of its features. I want to do a project in WF. It will be a web based intranet application where user will be able to define workflow dynamically through web interface. Duration for completing a task can be many days.

With these requirments I am not sure will use of WF helpful in quick development or it will increase work ?

Please advice me should I try to learn WF for this project or should do it with C# and asp.net

thanks

haansi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your description, WF would be helpful here. The main reason I say this is that you say tasks can take Days to complete.

The time it will take you to learn WF will be less than what it would take you to recreate this functionality reliably.

Comment: That is a beautiful aspect of WF. Even an existing workflow that is already in progress can be altered/redefined at runtime.